# How can a string constant be used as a computed identifier in a union type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, computed-properties

I have the following union type:

```js
interface Cell {};

type CellInfo =
  | { Provisioned: Cell }
  | { Cloned: Cell };
```

Is there a way to use a computed property identifier instead of a string literal? E. g.

```js
interface Cell {};

const PROVISIONED = "Provisioned";

type CellInfo =
  | { [PROVISIONED]: Cell }
  | { Cloned: Cell };
```

This works. Now I'd like to use an object or an enum instead of individual constants. Enums cannot be used for computed properties, but this doesn't work either:

```js
interface Cell {};

const CELL_TYPE = {
    PROVISIONED: "Provisioned",
    CLONED: "CLONED",
};

type CellInfo =
  | { [CELL_TYPE.PROVISIONED]: Cell }
  | { [CELL_TYPE.CLONED]: Cell };
```

The computed property's error message is `A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.(1170)`.

Why is that and how can I do it?

Comment: Try adding `as const` to the end of your `CELL_TYPE` definition. Eg: `CELL_TYPE = { ... } as const;`. The problem is that without the const declaration, typescript infers the value types as simply `string`, and as noted in the error message, it must be a literal or a unique symbol, not just string.

Comment: That's it, @Crice! Thanks a lot, very simple. Do you want to write it as an answer so I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it, one already mentioned by @CRice, another one is do const assertion on individual properties, this is a more granular approach

```
interface Cell {};

const CELL_TYPE = {
    PROVISIONED: "Provisioned" as const,
    CLONED: "CLONED" as const,
};

type CellInfo =
  | { [CELL_TYPE.PROVISIONED]: Cell }
  | { [CELL_TYPE.CLONED]: Cell };
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIQDYeQbwL4DcAUEQgPYgDOYaAogDL0D6AKgJoAKtyAvLkckHIOAJQDyANQCSAZSliAcrQAiALmQAiDlDIA3YJWAUIAEw3I4lZOSpgANAKGp6ileo3PXy85esVqDoQkYACeAA4o6FhSIDBkvI4APrjIANqoDMzsXAB0opKy8krKALrqUdh4SSnpmayctDmexWVomJUEQA)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an enum instead of the const

```js
interface Cell {};

enum CellType {
  PROVISIONED = 'Provisioned',
  CLONED = 'Cloned'
}

type CellInfo =
  | { [CellType.PROVISIONED]: Cell }
  | { [CellType.CLONED]: Cell };
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIQDYeQbwL4DcAUERCAK4C2amGAKgJ4AOKORyyACgEoDyAagEkAyoN4A5AKIARZAF5kAck5QA9gDdgAZ2CqQEACaKANOzQAZCTPlLUGPYcVE8JMMxTosgkDFXyzAD64yADanvTuAHQ8AiJiUtIAugBcNFjILhxBOKHhjCyRqJYJKWnYhCRAA)

Comment: Weird, I thought that didn't work when I tried. Thanks!